# Best pattern to use with inheritance model

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance

I have a model whereby I have an abstract class (lets call it `Vehicle`) and several inherited classes, such as `Bike`, `Motorbike`, `Car`, `Van` etc. This is essentially a simplified version of a real world problem.

```
abstract class Vehicle
    int ID;
    int WheelCount;
    string OwnerName;

class Bike
    DateTime lastSafetyCheck;

class Motorbike
    int EngineCC

class Car
    double EngineSize

class Van
    double StorageCapacity
```

I have within my system an `IEnumerable<Vehicle>` which contains each of these. This is contained in a thread safe singleton class, essentially acting as an in-memory database.

I wish to have a method in my application (in either the singleton or a seperate class) which allows me to query for only a certain type of Vehicle.

Initially I considered a method like:

```
internal IEnumerable<T> GetVehicles<T>() where T : Vehicle
```

in order that I would be able to supply a type `T` which would specify the type I wish to retrieve. I know that I can then use typeof() in order to perform logic. But what I cannot figure out is how to return my values? I'm basically struggling with the contents of the method, and I am beginning to think there must be a design pattern out there which would make a lot more sense.

AK

Answer (score 6, accepted):

LINQ already has this method - [OfType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913.aspx):

```
var vans = Vehicales.OfType<Van>();
```

As an aside, to determine whether an instance is an instance of a type you do not need to use `typeof()`, you can use the [is](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scekt9xw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [as](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cscsdfbt%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) operators (and they can be used with generic types also):

```
if (vehicle is Van) ...
if (vehicle is T) ...
```

Or

```
var van = vehicle as Van;
if (van != null) ...

var instance = vehicle as T; // Will need T : class generic type constraint
if (instance != null) ...

var instance = vehicle as T?; // Will need T : struct generic type constraint
if (instance != null) ...
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know about OfType!

Comment: rich. You just beat me to the punch.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just use [OfType()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913.aspx)?

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913.aspx):

> Filters the elements of an IEnumerable based on a specified type.

---

Your code could look like this:

```
internal IEnumerable<T> GetVehicles<T>() where T : Vehicle
{
    return AllVehicles.OfType<T>();
}
```

Comment: Can't believe I missed that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you have a collection of Vehicles, and your method returns an IEnumerable instead, you should just be able to run the following

```
var cars = GetVehicles().OfType<Car>();
```

That way your method GetVehicles does not need to do any logic, and you can filter by type in the Linq call instead.